# Transition between different svg-filters - how to?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I do apply an svg-filter to my jpg-images and by hovering I want that filter to be off again.

So the filter looks like that

```
<svg version="1.1" width="0" height="0" class="filter-rot">
    <filter id="duotone" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="gray"></feColorMatrix>
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.098"></feFuncR>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.114"></feFuncG>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0.722"></feFuncB>
            <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1"></feFuncA>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

And the scss is then like that:

```
.sw_projekte figure img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    transition: 0.2s;
    -webkit-filter: url(#duotone);
    filter:  url(#duotone); /* For Firefox pre-35 */
    filter:  url(#duotone);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sw_projekte figure img:hover{
    filter:  none;
}
```

Both filters really work great, and the hovering also does something but there is no transition at all whilst hovering. Do I do something wrong or isn't that possible?

thanks!

Comment: If you want transitions you'll have to specify exactly what property values you want to change by SMIL animating them onmouseover

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want to do would be to have two copies of your element directly on top of one another.  Apply the filter to the one on top, then fade it out on hover (to reveal the other one underneath).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
}

.filtered {
  filter: url(#duotone);
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.filtered:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="0" height="0" class="filter-rot">
    <filter id="duotone" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="gray"></feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
</svg>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" width="300" height="300" class="filtered"/>
</div>
```

If you need to transition between two different filters, just apply the other filter to the rear element.